# Extract CSV from plotly plot

Tags: csv, plotly

I have a `.html` file which is a plot made with [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/). Is there an easy/already implemented way of creating a CSV with the data from this plot?

For example consider this plot (Python):

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris() # iris is a pandas DataFrame
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="petal_length", facet_col='species')
fig.write_html('plot.html',include_plotlyjs='cdn')
```

where `df` looks like this

```
     sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width    species  species_id
0             5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2     setosa           1
1             4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2     setosa           1
2             4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2     setosa           1
3             4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2     setosa           1
4             5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2     setosa           1
..            ...          ...           ...          ...        ...         ...
145           6.7          3.0           5.2          2.3  virginica           3
146           6.3          2.5           5.0          1.9  virginica           3
147           6.5          3.0           5.2          2.0  virginica           3
148           6.2          3.4           5.4          2.3  virginica           3
149           5.9          3.0           5.1          1.8  virginica           3

[150 rows x 6 columns]
```

and `plot.html` contains this plot:

[image]

If you open the `.html` file with a text editor you will find all the data shown in the plot spread out in some kind of dictionary or so, probably JavaScript? How can one recover a CSV as close as possible to `df` from this?

Not looking for a Python exclusive answer, it can be anything. However Python is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Datasets used by Plotly are available on their dedicated repository : [plotly/datasets](https://github.com/plotly/datasets).

The formats used are mainly CSV, JSON and GeoJSON. It happens that Iris data originally are in CSV format ([iris.csv](https://github.com/plotly/datasets/blob/master/iris.csv)), so if you need the whole set you can grab it from there.

Otherwise you can always use [`df.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: I am not interested in the datasets used by Plotly, that was just a simple example. I have a random plot (I made long ago) from which I want to recover the data shown as a CSV. Unfortunately I have no longer the data which produced the plot, only the plot.

Comment: Ok I better understand your problem now. So yes the only way would be to parse the data, probably in json, from the javascript part of the html file. Can you update your post to bring more details and so that we can see a few records of these data ?